# What does "cell analysis" mean in terms of medical imaging technique?

Tags: medical-imaging

A paper [says](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/31696163)

> To validate the effectiveness of using A-GAN for data augmentation, we assessed its performance on **cell analysis** in adaptive optics retinal imaging, which is a rapidly-changing medical imaging modality.

where "adaptive optics retinal imaging" seems some kind of [medical imaging technique](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/23066/17920).

I understand the basic concept of "[cell analysis](https://www.biocompare.com/Lab-Equipment/6861-Cell-Analysis-Equipment/)", what does "cell analysis" mean in this context?